# Coping files from multiple UNCs to multiple folders

Tags: powershell

I'm new to Powershell. I need to create script which will pull data from csv (two columns) Filepath,FolderName and copy files from UNC(filepath) to Folders(FolderName).

My CSV looks like:

```
FolderName,FilePath
c:\1234,\\Path\1
c:\2345,\\Path\2
c:\6789,\\Path\3
```

I was able to do part of the job using foreach loop. I can copy many files(from many UNCs) to one location within this loop. But how can I achieve to copy every file from FilePath column to FolderName location?

I assume the answer is trivial for many of you but it's not for me :( 
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You have a far better chance of getting an answer if you show your code.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of what you have tried. Otherwise this is considered off-topic for this site. That said, if you're unsure of how to parse the CSV, make an attempt to use `Import-Csv` to work with your dataset.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$csvPath = 'C:\myFiles\copy.csv'

$content = Import-Csv -Path $csvPath -Delimiter ','

foreach( $record in $content ) {
    Copy-Item -Path $record.FolderName -Destination $record.FilePath -Force
}
```